# How to change UIDocumentInteractionController preview screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uidocumentinteraction

We have a requirement to change `UIDocumentInteractionController` preview screen? Is it possible to change the rect of `UIDocumentInteractionController`? I want to open document preview in my custom view?

Comment: You can use UIWebView in your custom view.

Answer (score 0):

in creating an AIR Native Extension, I needed to create a view window for my custom view controller.

make sure you are doing:

```
#import "MyCustomViewController.h"
```

in my function:

```
MyCustomViewController *myViewController;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIWindow *win = [delegate window];
myViewController = [[MyCustomViewController alloc]init];
[win addSubview:myViewController.view];


[myViewController previewDocument: (parameters to method)];

return (_bridge FREObject)(myViewController);
```

where you implement this may be different depending on your structure.  Since I am using it as an ANE, I put it right into the Context function call.

hope it gives you a starting point if you haven't gotten it yet.